# Naming differences between project dependencies and :require

Tags: clojure, dependencies, package

When I look at something like, say, the *clojure.data.json* source code I can see a namespace looking, for example, like this:

```
(ns clojure.data.json...)
```

So when I want to *:require* that in my *.clj* Clojure files, I simply do something like this:

```
(ns so.example
    (:require [clojure.data.json :as json])
    ...
```

However in the dependencies in my *.clj* I have:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/data.json "0.2.4"]
```

So the *clojure.data.json* "became" *org.clojure/data.json*.

Now for, say, *server.socket* I have in my dependencies:

```
[server-socket "1.0.0"]
```

So this time no ".org" added, no slash, but the dot became a dash.

What's the relation between :require in Clojure source files and :dependencies in *project.clj*? Is there any "logic"?

How can I find what's the correct line to put in the dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

The dependency vectors in `project.clj` are the maven artifact coordinates to resolve the dependency by finding the appropriate jar. Leiningen will attempt to find the apropriate jars and add them to your classpath so that namespace definitions and other resources can be loaded from inside their archive contents at runtime. The `require` statement in your code specifies a resource to look for in the class path. For example if you require `clojure.data.json`, Clojure will look for a resource with the path `clojure/data/json.clj` somewhere in your classpath, and attempt to load the definition for the namespace `clojure.data.json` from that resource.

Answer (score 2):

There is no relationship. Namespace is something defined in the source code file. A dependency is based on a project name and is decided by the author(s) when they publish it. You'll almost always find the proper dependency information on the project github site or at Clojars, or in some cases, maven.